# Help with Equation

Tags: computational-mathematics

I have no idea what im doing but would like some help please

I am creating a website based on a scoring system and would like help with part of an equation:

I have a Base Score(b), Individual Score(i), and would like to add a kind of multiplier value(m).

So I would like the Individual Score(i) to adjust the Base Score(b) but would like the multiplier value to influence how much of an impact that Individual Score(i) has.

Both the Base Score and Individual Score will have values between 1-100, at the moment I am using:

((i * 2)/100) * b

but have no idea how to add the multiplier

so some of the values could be:

b = 50
i = 40
m = 2 (where 2 would mean the individual score has twice the impact)

b = 30
i = 70
m = 1 (where 1 would mean the individual score has standard impact)

b = 50
i = 60
m = 0.5 (where 0.5 would mean the individual score has half the impact)

Answer (score 1):

You could use
$$\text{Score}=b+(i\times m)$$

As you multiply $i$ with $m$, the "impact" of the value added to the base $b$ is adjusted based on $m$.